# Explicit wait for a selector isn't working?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm writing a code to log in Gmail. On the password page, instead of using implicit wait, I want to use explicit wait instead. However, it is not picking up my selector?

```
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/');
await page.$('#identifierId');
await page.keyboard.type('Test1234');
await page.click('#identifierNext > content > span');

await page.waitForSelector('#password'); //this doesnt work
// await page.waitFor(5000); this works
await page.$('#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input');
await page.keyboard.type('fakePassword');
await page.click('#passwordNext > content');
);
```

I'm getting the error:

> (node:14428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
>       at ElementHandle._clickablePoint (/Users/asd/Projects/FreeRazor/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/JSHandle.js:199:13)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
>     -- ASYNC --
>       at ElementHandle. (/Users/asd/Projects/FreeRazor/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
>       at DOMWorld.click (/Users/asd/Projects/FreeRazor/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:367:18)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
>     -- ASYNC --
>       at Frame. (/Users/asd/Projects/FreeRazor/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
>       at Page.click (/Users/asd/Projects/FreeRazor/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:988:29)
>       at /Users/asd/Projects/FreeRazor/app.js:19:16
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
>   (node:14428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:14428) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 1):

The `page.waitForSelector` statement is working. One of the `page.click` calls is the problem.

**Relevant part of the error message:**

```js
(node:14428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
    [...]
    at Page.click (/Users/asd/Projects/FreeRazor/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:988:29)
    at /Users/asd/Projects/FreeRazor/app.js:19:16
```

So the error happens in line 19. I don't know for sure which line it is, but I'm assuming it is the latter `page.click` call as you are saying the code works if you wait longer (`page.waitFor(5000)`). So it seems it takes the page longer to display the `#passwordNext > content` DOM element than the `#password` element.

#### Solution

You can solve this problem by putting another `waitForSelector` before your click to make sure the element actually exists. I even added the option `{ visible: true }` to make sure the DOM node is also visible:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#passwordNext > content', { visible: true });
await page.click('#passwordNext > content');
```